# Saving cell accessory to NSUserDefaults

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, nsuserdefaults

I've previously asked a question which was answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14073819/saving-state-of-uitableview-cell-accessory) regarding saving the state of of a cell accessory. I'm now playing with NSUserDefaults. I've successfully saved a number of options in my app but can't seem to save the state of the cell accessory to NSUserDefaults.

After a number of tries, I've come to the conclusion I don't know what or where to save as well as where to recall the saved options.

Can anyoone point me in the right direction?

Thanks,

EDIT: Whilst I understand the variable will likely need to be converted, I'm having a hard time what needs to be converted and when.

Comment: Are you aware that you first have to convert it to a NSData object?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the question that you cite the code snippets use an instance variable named `_accessoryStyle`. The variable has the type `NSMutableArray`. Assuming that you still have this variable, you can simply save its content to the user defaults like this:

```
NSUserDefaults* userDefaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
[userDefaults setObject:self._accessoryStyle forKey:@"aKeyName"];
```

If you later want to retrieve the data, you can do it like this:

```
NSUserDefaults* userDefaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
NSArray* immutableData = [userDefaults arrayForKey:@"aKeyName"]];
[self._accessoryStyle setArray:immutableData];
```

Retrieving is slightly more complicated because `arrayForKey:` returns an immutable `NSArray`, not an `NSMutableArray`.

Comment: @mattFllr Good to see that my answers are helpful :-) Just don't forget to consult the documentation provided by Apple before you ask a question on SO. For this specific question, the class documentation for `NSUserDefaults` ([link](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSUserDefaults_Class/Reference/Reference.html)) could have told you everything that you needed to know. Of course, my advice needs to be taken with a grain of salt since it is sometimes difficult to find the right piece of documentation...

Answer (score 0):

For objects that aren't NSData, NSDate, NSString, NSArray, NSDictionary, NSNumber (since they can't be saved on a plist file), you could use these macros:

```
#define SetDefaultObjectForKey(object, key) [ [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject: [NSKeyedArchiver archivedDataWithRootObject: object] forKey: key]

#define GetDefaultObjectForkey(key) [NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchivedObjectWithData: [ [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey: key] ]
```

So you are converting them to NSData when saving, and decoding them from NSData to their original type when reading, provided that the object implements the NSCoding protocol. If not so, you should provide an implementation.

Comment: The issue I'm having is identifying what needs to be converted, where and where to recall. See herzbube's answered code in previous question. Thanks.